# How to add a variable into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
t = 0
prices = x
for t in range(0,5):
    t += 1
    prices@t = y
```

I want the price variable to change based on `t`, like `prices1`, `prices2`, `prices3`, etc.

Comment: Have you looked at [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. why not just use array?

Comment: Given it looks like t is just an index, a list is probably sufficient, `prices[t]`

Comment: I already have it it as a list – prices = [] but I wish to capture an updated price list every few seconds.

Comment: I'm sure what you're asking for is possible, but it's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking for. Can you give some examples of input and the output you're looking for?

Comment: With a `list` you can't assign a value with an arbitrary key, which addresses what questioner specified in this vague question.

Comment: I could eg manually name the variables prices1, prices2, prices3, etc but I was just curious whether I could generate them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't be automatically creating local variables. It's best to keep a collection of similar values in a container variable of some type

You can use a `list` for this

```
prices = []
for t in range(0, 5):
    prices.append(y)
```

or if you want to preallocate a list of the right size:

```
prices = [0] * 5
for t in range(0, 5):
    prices[t] = y
```

Alternatively a `dict`

```
prices = {}
for t in range(0, 5):
    prices[t] = y
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to be creating local variables automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution for the problem, but you can use exec() to accomplish this

```
y = 10
for t in range(0,5):
    y = y+t
    exec("prices"+ str(t) + "= y")
print(prices0)
print(prices1)
print(prices2)
print(prices3)
```